# Why does my script not find inactive GameObject when it should?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that should toggle active on my GameObject but when it disables it, it no longer finds the object.

Script:

```
GameObject cheet = GameObject.Find("base");

if (isOpen == true)
{
    cheet.SetActive(true);
}
else
{
    cheet.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: because `Find` searches for only active game objects. To fix that, just add a public class field e.g. `public GameObject cheet` then in `void Start()` add `cheet = GameObject.Find("base");` and it should work.

Comment: `isOpen` already contains the value you need for the `SetActive` parameter, so you can simply pass it to the method `cheet.SetActive(isOpen);`, just as you would for an `int` or `string` parameter. `bool` is not any different in this respect. No need for an `if else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GameObject.Find](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) only returns active GameObjects, so I would recommend storing a reference to cheet in `Start()` or `Awake()`. As long as Cheet exists, this will ensure you have a reference and you only have to do it once.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject cheet;
    private bool isOpen; // Temp isOpen variable

    void Start()
    {
        // Store a reference to the GameObject
        cheet = GameObject.Find("base");
    }

    void Example1()
    {
        // set active based on varable isOpen
        cheet?.SetActive(isOpen);
    }

    void Example2()
    {
        // Could not find cheet (null)
        if(cheet == null)
            return;

        // set active based on varable isOpen
        cheet.SetActive(isOpen);
    }
}
```